# InvalidCastException using Linq to DataSet (OleDb)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, oledb

I started with using DataSet with OleDB. While reading the CSV, data in one of the columns is formatted as strings, while these are in fact numeric values (basically integers) which I would like to compare vs. given condition (extract ones > 0 ) with WHERE clause. I have no good idea how to go about converting these string values to integers, so I can do some math on them and not get stopped by InvalidCastException.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string csvFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["csvFile"];

    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
    + csvFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=true;FMT=Delimited\"";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [DE.csv]", csvFile);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";

        var lista = ds.Tables["Table1"]
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<int>("#_Comp#") > 0) // // Invalid Cast Exception (!!)
            .Select(i => new { Name = i.Field<int>("#_Comp#") }); 

        Console.WriteLine(lista.Count());

    }

}
```

Comment: You can confirm that in ALL rows #_Comp# is convertable to int? No nulls no empty strings?

Comment: I check in Excel that all values are there filled in. In notepad++ the figures are returned in quotes, which is not happening in excel - I have not yet tried if these quotes could be an issue.

Comment: Take a look in ds.Tables[0] while debuggimg and simply look if quotes are there or not. I would assume not. Then replace the casting with a conversion. Either Int.Parse or Convert.ToString. A string is not an int and can't be casted even if the string content look loke a number. (int)"0"  is not valid.

Comment: thank you for looking into this .Where(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Field<string>("#_Comp#")) > 0) did the trick. The quotes were showing in visual studio.